When saving in Json format, some places I want are not saved
I'm making a game in Unity and I'm using json format to save. I have no problem recording it on my computer, but it does not record the animals I catch on my Android phone. How can I solve this? What is the reason?
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class KayitHayvanSlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject HayvanPaneliGO;
    public GameObject Player;
    HayvanPaneliKod HayvanPaneliKod;
    public HayvanDatas hayvanDatas;

    //------------------------
    private void Awake()
    {
        HayvanYukle();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        HayvanPaneliKod = HayvanPaneliGO.GetComponent<HayvanPaneliKod>();
        Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hayvanlarSave.json");

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hayvanlarSave.json"))
        {
            HayvanTakas2();
        }

        Debug.Log("Bu script " + gameObject.name + " objesine bağlıdır.");
    }
    private void HayvanYukle()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hayvanlarSave.json"))
        {
            JsonYukle();
        }
    }
    public void JsonKaydet()
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(hayvanDatas, true);
        Debug.Log(jsonString);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hayvanlarSave.json", jsonString);
    }
    public void JsonYukle()
    {
        string jsonOku = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hayvanlarSave.json");
        hayvanDatas = JsonUtility.FromJson<HayvanDatas>(jsonOku);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------

    public void HayvanTakas()
    {
        for (int i = 0; HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar.Count > i; i++)
        {
            if (HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i] != null)
            {
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanismi = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanismi;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanbilgi = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanbilgi;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanid = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanid;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanatak = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanatak;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvandefans = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvandefans;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancan = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvancan;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancandolu = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvancandolu;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].kazanılanTecrübe = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].kazanılanTecrübe;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanlevel = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanlevel;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvantipi = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvantipi;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanYakalandiTF = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanYakalandiTF;
            }
        }
    }

    public void HayvanTakas2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; 70 > i; i++)
        {
            if (hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanid != 0)
            {
                Hayvan yenihayvan = new Hayvan(hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanismi, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanbilgi,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanid, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanatak,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvandefans, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancan,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancandolu, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].kazanılanTecrübe,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanlevel, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvantipi,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanYakalandiTF);

                HayvanPaneliKod.SeciliSlotaHayvanEkle(yenihayvan, i);
            }
        }

    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class HayvanData
{
    public string hayvanismi;
    public string hayvanbilgi;
    public int hayvanid;
    public float hayvanatak;
    public float hayvandefans;
    public float hayvancan;
    public float hayvancandolu;
    public int kazanılanTecrübe;
    public int hayvanlevel;
    public Hayvan.HayvanType hayvantipi;
    public bool hayvanYakalandiTF;

    public HayvanData()
    {

    }

    public HayvanData(string hayvanismi, string hayvanbilgi, int hayvanid, float hayvanatak, float hayvandefans, float hayvancan,
                      float hayvancandolu, int kazanılanTecrübe, int hayvanlevel, Hayvan.HayvanType hayvantipi, bool hayvanYakalandiTF)
    {
        this.hayvanismi = hayvanismi;
        this.hayvanbilgi = hayvanbilgi;
        this.hayvanid = hayvanid;
        this.hayvanatak = hayvanatak;
        this.hayvandefans = hayvandefans;
        this.hayvancan = hayvancan;
        this.hayvancandolu = hayvancandolu;
        this.kazanılanTecrübe = kazanılanTecrübe;
        this.hayvanlevel = hayvanlevel;
        this.hayvantipi = hayvantipi;
        this.hayvanYakalandiTF = hayvanYakalandiTF;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class HayvanDatas
{
    public List<HayvanData> dataHayvans = new List<HayvanData>();
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TopluKayit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject TarlaEkimArayuzGO1;
    public GameObject TarlaEkimArayuzGO2;
    public GameObject TarlaEkimArayuzGO3;

    public GameObject KayitEnvanterSlotGO;
    public GameObject KaydetmePanelEHGO;
    public GameObject BitkiToplaArayuzGO;
    public GameObject EnvanterGO;

    public List<GameObject> MaviTotemGOs;
    public List<GameObject> SariTotemGOs;
    public List<GameObject> FareTotemGOs;
    public GameObject YarasaGO;

    KayitYetenekSlot KayitYetenekSlot;
    KayitYetenekRuhAtak KayitYetenekRuhAtak;
    KayitYetenekLevel KayitYetenekLevel;
    KayitKarakter KayitKarakter;
    KayitHayvanSlot KayitHayvanSlot;
    DevHayvanAdamKayit DevHayvanAdamKayit;
    GorevKayit GorevKayit;
    DogaKayit DogaKayit;
    BitkiKayit BitkiKayit;
    KayitEnvanterSlot KayitEnvanterSlot;

    List<Totemler> MaviTotems;
    List<Totemler> SariTotems;
    List<Totemler> FareTotems;
    Totemler YarasaTotem;

    Envanter Envanter;

    TarlaEkim TarlaEkimArayuz1;
    TarlaEkim TarlaEkimArayuz2;
    TarlaEkim TarlaEkimArayuz3;

    private void Start()
    {
        KayitYetenekSlot = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<KayitYetenekSlot>();
        KayitYetenekRuhAtak = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<KayitYetenekRuhAtak>();
        KayitYetenekLevel = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<KayitYetenekLevel>();
        KayitKarakter = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<KayitKarakter>();
        KayitHayvanSlot = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<KayitHayvanSlot>();
        DevHayvanAdamKayit = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<DevHayvanAdamKayit>();
        GorevKayit = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<GorevKayit>();
        DogaKayit = BitkiToplaArayuzGO.GetComponent<DogaKayit>();
        BitkiKayit = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<BitkiKayit>();
        KayitEnvanterSlot = KayitEnvanterSlotGO.GetComponent<KayitEnvanterSlot>();
        Envanter = EnvanterGO.GetComponent<Envanter>();
        

        for (int i = 0; MaviTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            MaviTotems = new List<Totemler>();
        }
        for (int i = 0; SariTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            SariTotems = new List<Totemler>();
        }
        for (int i = 0; FareTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            FareTotems = new List<Totemler>();
        }

        YarasaTotem = new Totemler();


        for (int i = 0; MaviTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            MaviTotems.Add(MaviTotemGOs[i].GetComponent<Totemler>());
        }
        for (int i = 0; SariTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            SariTotems.Add(SariTotemGOs[i].GetComponent<Totemler>());
        }
        for (int i = 0; FareTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            FareTotems.Add(FareTotemGOs[i].GetComponent<Totemler>());
        }

        YarasaTotem = YarasaGO.GetComponent<Totemler>();

        TarlaEkimArayuz1 = TarlaEkimArayuzGO1.GetComponent<TarlaEkim>();
        TarlaEkimArayuz2 = TarlaEkimArayuzGO2.GetComponent<TarlaEkim>();
        TarlaEkimArayuz3 = TarlaEkimArayuzGO3.GetComponent<TarlaEkim>();
    }

    public void DataTakaslar()
    {
        KaydetmePanelEHGO.SetActive(true);
        KayitYetenekSlot.YetenekTakas();
        KayitYetenekRuhAtak.Takas1();
        KayitYetenekLevel.Takas1();

        KayitKarakter.TepeHayvani();
        //StartCoroutine(KayitKarakter.TotemKaydetme1Cor());
        KayitKarakter.ItemTakas();
        KayitKarakter.BagKurulanHayvanTakas1();
        KayitKarakter.YetenekKisitlamaTakas1();
        KayitKarakter.HangiSehirde();
        KayitKarakter.HangiSehirde();
        KayitKarakter.TepeHayvani();

        KayitEnvanterSlot.ItemTakas();

        GorevKayit.DataTakas();
        GorevKayit.DataTakas3();
        GorevKayit.DataTakas5();
        GorevKayit.DataTakas7();

        DogaKayit.TekBitkiZamanCor();
        DogaKayit.BitkiSayisiOrtaCor();
        DogaKayit.BitkiSayisiCokCor();

        BitkiKayit.DataTakas();

        KayitHayvanSlot.HayvanTakas();

        DevHayvanAdamKayit.DataTakas();

        for (int i = 0; MaviTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            MaviTotems[i].ItemTakas();
        }
        for (int i = 0; SariTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            SariTotems[i].ItemTakas();
        }
        for (int i = 0; FareTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            FareTotems[i].ItemTakas();
        }

        YarasaTotem.ItemTakas();

        Envanter.ItemTakas();


        TarlaEkimArayuz1.BitkiSayisiCor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz1.BitkiSayisi2Cor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz1.TekBitkiZamanCor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz2.BitkiSayisiCor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz2.BitkiSayisi2Cor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz2.TekBitkiZamanCor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz3.BitkiSayisiCor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz3.BitkiSayisi2Cor();
        TarlaEkimArayuz3.TekBitkiZamanCor();
    }

    public void Kaydetmeler()
    {
        KayitEnvanterSlot.JsonKaydet();
        KayitYetenekSlot.JsonKaydet();
        KayitYetenekRuhAtak.JsonKaydet();
        KayitYetenekLevel.JsonKaydet();
        KayitKarakter.JsonKaydet();
        GorevKayit.JsonKaydet();
        DogaKayit.JsonKaydet();
        BitkiKayit.JsonKaydet();
        KayitHayvanSlot.JsonKaydet();
        DevHayvanAdamKayit.JsonKaydet();

        for (int i = 0; MaviTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            MaviTotems[i].JsonKaydet();
        }
        for (int i = 0; SariTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            SariTotems[i].JsonKaydet();
        }
        for (int i = 0; FareTotemGOs.Count > i; i++)
        {
            FareTotems[i].JsonKaydet();
        }

        YarasaTotem.JsonKaydet();
        Envanter.JsonKaydet();

        TarlaEkimArayuz1.JsonKaydet();
        TarlaEkimArayuz2.JsonKaydet();
        TarlaEkimArayuz3.JsonKaydet();

        KaydetmeKapat();
    }

    public void KaydetmeKapat()
    {
        KaydetmePanelEHGO.SetActive(false);
    }
}

Below is the working code I wrote.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

public class KayitHayvanSlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject HayvanPaneliGO;
    public GameObject Player;
    HayvanPaneliKod HayvanPaneliKod;
    public HayvanDatas hayvanDatas;


    //------------------------
    private void Awake()
    {
        HayvanYukle();
    }

    IEnumerator DataCekme()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "hayvanlarSave.json")));

        HayvanTakas2();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        HayvanPaneliKod = HayvanPaneliGO.GetComponent<HayvanPaneliKod>();
        Debug.Log(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "hayvanlarSave.json"));

        StartCoroutine(DataCekme());

        Debug.Log("Bu script " + gameObject.name + " objesine bağlıdır.");
    }
    private void HayvanYukle()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "hayvanlarSave.json")))
        {
            JsonYukle();
        }
    }
    public void JsonKaydet()
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(hayvanDatas, true);
        Debug.Log(jsonString);
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "hayvanlarSave.json"), jsonString);
    }
    public void JsonYukle()
    {
        string jsonOku = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "hayvanlarSave.json"));
        hayvanDatas = JsonUtility.FromJson<HayvanDatas>(jsonOku);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------

    public void HayvanTakas()
    {
        for (int i = 0; HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar.Count > i; i++)
        {
            if (HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i] != null)
            {
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanismi = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanismi;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanbilgi = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanbilgi;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanid = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanid;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanatak = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanatak;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvandefans = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvandefans;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancan = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvancan;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancandolu = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvancandolu;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].kazanılanTecrübe = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].kazanılanTecrübe;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanlevel = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanlevel;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvantipi = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvantipi;
                hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanYakalandiTF = HayvanPaneliKod.hayvanlar[i].hayvanYakalandiTF;
            }
        }
    }

    public void HayvanTakas2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; 70 > i; i++)
        {
            if (hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanid != 0)
            {
                Hayvan yenihayvan = new Hayvan(hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanismi, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanbilgi,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanid, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanatak,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvandefans, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancan,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvancandolu, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].kazanılanTecrübe,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanlevel, hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvantipi,
                                               hayvanDatas.dataHayvans[i].hayvanYakalandiTF);

                HayvanPaneliKod.SeciliSlotaHayvanEkle(yenihayvan, i);
            }
        }

    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------


[System.Serializable]
public class HayvanData
{
    public string hayvanismi;
    public string hayvanbilgi;
    public int hayvanid;
    public float hayvanatak;
    public float hayvandefans;
    public float hayvancan;
    public float hayvancandolu;
    public int kazanılanTecrübe;
    public int hayvanlevel;
    public Hayvan.HayvanType hayvantipi;
    public bool hayvanYakalandiTF;

    public HayvanData()
    {

    }

    public HayvanData(string hayvanismi, string hayvanbilgi, int hayvanid, float hayvanatak, float hayvandefans, float hayvancan,
                      float hayvancandolu, int kazanılanTecrübe, int hayvanlevel, Hayvan.HayvanType hayvantipi, bool hayvanYakalandiTF)
    {
        this.hayvanismi = hayvanismi;
        this.hayvanbilgi = hayvanbilgi;
        this.hayvanid = hayvanid;
        this.hayvanatak = hayvanatak;
        this.hayvandefans = hayvandefans;
        this.hayvancan = hayvancan;
        this.hayvancandolu = hayvancandolu;
        this.kazanılanTecrübe = kazanılanTecrübe;
        this.hayvanlevel = hayvanlevel;
        this.hayvantipi = hayvantipi;
        this.hayvanYakalandiTF = hayvanYakalandiTF;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class HayvanDatas
{
    public List<HayvanData> dataHayvans = new List<HayvanData>();
}'''


I think it looks like a permissions issue. But what confuses me is that most of my registration codes work, the code I made to catch animals does not work on mobile.

I wrote two code scripts, with one code script I get the values ​​of the animals I catch and with the other I save them. There are also values ​​I got from different scripts where I saved them. Here's how I do the recording. I press a key and get the values ​​from DataTakaslar(). When I press the Yes button, Kaydetmeler() works and everything is saved.

I solved my problem, not only on Android but also on PC, it was not saving when compiled. So, I put a waiting condition on the data I pulled at start with a coroutine so that the data would not be pulled until the file was created, and the code I wrote worked. The code I sent you is a working version. Thank you very much for your answers so far.

Jave you tried saving on a pc build? If it foes not work there either, it is rather a code error and if it does work it's an android specific error.

@CheckerT It was working smoothly in the editor. I was compiling for Android, so I thought the fault was in Android, but when I compiled for PC, the saving part was also problematic. So, I edited the code and it worked. Thank you very much for your answer, I have already explained how I solved the problem.

This looks like an Android permissions issue. You need to ask the user for permission to write files. See Android.Permission.
Try this:
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
            {
                Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
            }
#endif


I'll look into Android.Permission
